# hex string to int conversion not working correctly

Tags: java, android, hex

I have a hexidecimal number (a color) stored in a String as followed: "ff62e6b8".
I need to convert this back to an integer so I can use it as a color value again.
I have tried the following:

```
Int i = Integer.parseInt("ff62e6b8", 16);
Int i = Integer.valueOf("ff62e6b8", 16);
Int i = Integer.decode("ff62e6b8");
```

But all of these methods raise exceptions. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this :

```
int colorVal = Color.parseColor("#ff62e6b8");
```

**Example :**

```
myLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff62e6b8"));
```

By this you will get `colorVal = -10295624`.

And if you want to generate **hexColor code back from the colorVal** then use this :

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & colorVal));
```

By this you will get `hexColor = #62E6B8`.

Thanks.

Comment: @BrunoCarvalhal I just edited my solution which will be more helpful in case of need. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

FF62E6B8 is 4284671672 in decimal. It's simply to large to put it into `int`. In `int` you can store values which match the range `<-2^31 - 1 ; 2^31 - 1>`. Try to use `long` instead:

```
Long i = Long.parseInt("ff62e6b8", 16);
Long i = Long.valueOf("ff62e6b8", 16);
Long i = Long.decode("ff62e6b8");
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot. But can you use long values as color values? Is there a way to convert the string "ff62e6b8" back to the integer 0xff62e6b8?

Comment: I think that you are looking for Pratik Sharma solution :)

Comment: @AdamSznajder I just edited my solution which will be more helpful in case of need and thanks for suggesting my name. :)

Answer (score 1):

the first one would be the good one

but ff62e6b8 exceeds the size of int (32 bit - signed), that's why an exception is raised.

```
Long l = Long.parseLong("ff62e6b8", 16);
```

should do the job

Answer (score 0):

```
String hex = "1B";
int val = Integer.parseInt(hex, 16);
```

That is the correct conversion.